# ASPX file won't recognize <section> tag?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have this aspx file and I'm trying to use , but whenever I use it I got the green line under it with the following error:
Element "section" is not supported.

And I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

```
 <section id="Section1"><div class="inner"><h2>This is Head2</h2><ul class="actions"><li><a href="#content" class="button big special">Sign Up</a></li><li><a href="#elements" class="button big alt">Learn More</a></li></ul></div></section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`section`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) element is new in HTML5, so it should only be used in HTML documents that start with the HTML5 [doctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Introduction_to_HTML5):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

What doctype is declared at the top of your master page or layout file?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: OK, so if you change that to `<!DOCTYPE html>` the error should go away. (I've tested and verified this in VS2012)